# Protect source code of an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, security, obfuscation

In our college they have  competition--students have to develop and show some code.  It has a cash prize.  I have done an entry as a website (C#) using asp.net.  The problem is that my website is in the computer laboratory of the college, so anybody can open Visual Studio and copy my project or edit it.

I want to protect my project.  Is there any way to put password for the project alone in Visual Studio?  To make it attractive I have hosted the website in the IIS of the server, so by using the IP adresss I can run the project anywhere with intranet access.

When I put a lock like EasyFileLocker, I am unable to open and run the project using the IP address.

I want to run my project anywhere in the intranet, but also protect its code.

How can I do that?

Comment: Stick it on a USB, copy to the computer only when you need to show it and delete afterwards?

Comment: I hope your C# project is formatted better than your question (and spell checked)!

Comment: If you dont have a TFS or some versionning server to hold your source code at your college, you might want to consider transfering to a better college, or host your own on Google Code. With that, you can checkout your project, work on it, commit the changes, then delete the project from the PC until you want to work on it again.

Comment: @trickery i hosted the project in the college server so that from any department they can run my project(the project is used for mark analysis)

Answer (score 3):

Presuming your source code is somewhere safe (if not, then put it somewhere safe over which you have control), then the deployed end result need not expose the source code in its raw format; you can pre-compile ASP.NET websites entirely (such that even the markup can't be edited on the server - at least not very easily) - do this by selecting the pre-compilation options on the deploy screen, being sure to uncheck "allow this website to be updatable".

the exact method of specifying the right build options differs between VS versions, but the options are the same ultimately: Precompile, (Don't) Allow precompiled site to be updatable.

The result is the code of your website ending up in binaries, including the page markup (the files still exist, but simply as placeholders with their substance missing.) For someone to get at your code, they'd need to reflect your binaries.

Comment: Thank you @Grant thomas i will try it and let you know :)